# prove that $∀ε>0∃p∈P(U(f,p)−L(f,p)<ε)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals, riemann-sum

$F:[0,1]\times[0,1]\longrightarrow R$

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{y<x} \\
0, & \text{y $\geqslant$x}
\end{cases}
$

i have a problem choosing my p∈P
and proving the statement 
any guidance would be great

Comment: What is F in your problem?

Comment: @SomabhaMukherjee $f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{y<x} \\
0, & \text{y $\geqslant$x}
\end{cases} $

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_N$ be a partition of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ into a mesh of $N \times N$ equally sized squares (each has an area of $1/N^2)$. The difference $U(f,P_N)-L(f,P_N)$ then equals $1/N$ (why?). Taking $N>1/\varepsilon$ gets the job done.

Comment: U(f,PN)−L(f,PN) = 1/N

because L(f,PN) =0 

U(f,PN) = [ N * 1/N^2 ] * 1 ?

Comment: Not exactly. The upper and lower values agree everywhere except on the squares lying on the diagonal $y=x$.

Comment: you got N squares lying on the diagonal y=x so.. N * (1/N^2) * 1 = 1/N ?

Comment: @NizarHalloun Yes.